# Tutorials/video/examples for Thunderbird add-ons programming using Mozilla Jetpack

Tags: javascript, email, mozilla

Been searching for Tutorials, videos or examples of Thunderbird add-ons programming using Mozilla Jetpack

Anybody know of a good source for tutorials/videos/examples for Thunderbird add-ons programming using Mozilla Jetpack

I've been searching through the net and cant find nothing that is relevant, actual (less than a year old) and well explained (good examples)...

?anybody know of a good source of info about this...
Please do not point to MDN or other Mozilla sites... no good samples there for Thunderbird... just a few usable samples for Firefox...